# Can someone help me to fix table.getn

Tags: lua

I have a table with these code but can now its always show

> [string "luavm"]:52: attempt to call a nil value (field 'getn')

here is my code

```
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) and indexPattern < table.getn(Wpattern[indexWeapon]) or IsModifierPressed("lshift") and indexPattern < table.getn(Wpattern[indexWeapon]) then            
                MoveMouseRelative(Wpattern[indexWeapon][indexPattern].x*sensibility[indexWeapon]* RecoilSense, Wpattern[indexWeapon][indexPattern].y*sensibility[indexWeapon]*RecoilSense)
                Sleep(delay)
                indexPattern = indexPattern + 1
            else
```

Comment: here is full of scrip

Answer (score 2):

The version of Lua you are using doesn't provide `getn` method, as it's been deprecated since Lua 5.1. You can use the [length (`#`) operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7) to get the number of elements in a table without holes (`nil` values).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Lua version not match your script code. try lua 5.0 that support table.getn

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575241/after-table-getn-got-deprected-in-logitech-5-4-lua-this-code-doesnt-seems-to-wo/65580286#65580286) question on how to add `table.getn` yourself.